# How to use Kafka connector using java code?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Currently I am using Kafka SpoolDir connector in standalone mode. After adding the required configurations to the properties file, I start the connector using

```
kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties file-source.properties
```

Is there any way to start the connector(stadalone/ distributed) using a java code only, in the way we can write consumer and producer java codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectStandalone` is the Java class that this command starts, but Connect Framework is not meant to be ran as an embedded service

You can see [the source code here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/cli/ConnectStandalone.java#L86-L127) that starts the server and parses the config file

Comment: Thank you for this information. But the doubt I still have is that the Kafka connector i am trying to implement is to be pushed into production. That is why i was searching for a way using java. How should I go about it? I am sorry if this is a silly question to ask, I am totally new to this.

Comment: The linked code is "using Java". That shell script you asked about runs the class I linked to... However, you should be using `connect-distributed`. Kafka Connectors are typically JAR files placed on the `plugin.path` config of production servers (seen in `connect-distributed.properties`).

Comment: Okay. So I should use connect-distributed and after adding the properties file, start the connector using the corresponding shell command only, is this correct?

Comment: The property file is already available from any Kafka installation. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html

Comment: Oh yes, I meant customising the properties. But I got your point. Thankyou!